# Sort Files in FAT32 without copy them again

Tags: java, sorting

I wrote a little program that uses comparators to copy files on a FAT32 drive in the order I want. E.g. alphabetical or smallest file first. (Thanks to Java 7)

But if I add new files to the FAT32 drive, all files need to be sorted and copied again, to ensure a correct order.

Is there a way to manipulate the FAT32 table with java? Or another easy solution to sort files without copying?

I am new in the programing world, so I am happy the program works at all. :)

Comment: I don't understand. Files in a folder are not guaranteed to be sorted in any order. The order that FAT32 uses to store the file list is just an implementation detail and should not matter in your program. Why do you need this?

Comment: I wanted so sort the files of my car radio. So right now, I can sort alphabetical, by size, creation date...  Java helps me to copy the files on the FAT32 device in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

- create a new directory
- move (not copy) the files in the order you want using File.rename()
- delete the old directory.
- rename the new directory as the old one.

Comment: Thank you, sounds like a very good idea. I will try to programm it.