# sorting files on a fat32 usb

Tags: c#, sorting, fat32

im making an app to sort the files in a directory into the same order as a list box and now im trying to make it sort the file on the fat32 file table but cant find out how or if i can do this on c# can anyone help me heres the code that adds the files to the list box

```
private void openfolder()
{
     if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
          DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
          FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.*");
          foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
          {
              listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: There is not really such a thing as sorting files in a directory. It's only the program displaying that sorts. At least, not at any useful level - and not at the level of code you are working at.

Comment: its to sort file for cd players and stuff theres programs that do it like fatsort but i want more control over it thus this program i know i can do this in c++ but i havent learnt c++ yet so i was wondering if i could do it in c#

Comment: Ahhh... shoulda mentioned that! One rare case where it does make sense!

Comment: lol np as i said i want to sort the file in any order i want not just alphabetically im about to look at fatsorter source to see if it can help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Files in FAT32 without copy them again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823729/sort-files-in-fat32-without-copy-them-again)

Comment: @spender thats in java and also they didnt have any code so doesnt help and not a dup

Comment: The accepted answer tells you exactly what to do...

Comment: but its not what i need i need to sort hundreds of files in one hit i was trying to avoid code that moves them into a new folder then move them back in correct order

Comment: I don't buy it. Moving the file is not a copy/delete operation. It just shuffles the allocation table around. It will be quick.

Comment: What about solutions listed here(http://www.murraymoffatt.com/software-problem-0010.html)? Some of them have description on their approach so you could use it as guide.

Comment: none of them have manual file sorting like i want i want to be able to put my favorites first and not in alphabetical like all those. anyway doesnt matter i decided to go with the move file to temp folder and then move back in correct order

Comment: @outlaw1994 [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95721/FAT-Sorter) sample should be good for your modifications, by default is sorts alphabetically so you will have to change this order, alternatively provide order from some gui of yours.

Comment: @PTwr i found that before but its in c++ not c# so it doesnt help much

Comment: @outlaw1994 from what I see, you can supply modified data file to this console application, thus changes to its code won't be necessary as you can control console applications from .NET code - ([sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79620/Run-console-application-from-a-NET-application]))

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So it goes something like this:

```
var path = @"U:\";
var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var files = di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
var newDirPath = Path.Combine(path,Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
di = Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirPath);
files.ForEach(f => f.MoveTo(Path.Combine(newDirPath, f.Name)));
files=di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .OrderBy(f=>f.CreationTime) //sort here
        .ToList();
files.ForEach(f=>f.MoveTo(Path.Combine(path,f.Name)));
Directory.Delete(newDirPath);
```

Your objection to moving files is ill-founded. The move operation does not copy data. It merely changes the allocation table.

Comment: i want to change the allocation data cause thats how my cd player and a lot of others sort. they use the allocation data

Comment: @outlaw1994 : I did a bit of reading, and this is the way you do it. Did you try this approach? What makes you think you have to do some low-level manipulation?

Comment: cause thats how all the other progs did it in c++. i will try this way but looking at the code it sorts them by creation time how would i sort it to the same order as the list